# I am setting "placement:top" for the tippy tooltip but the tooltip is placed at the top-start position (maybe due to the padding )

Tags: javascript, jquery, tooltip, tippyjs

## *Calling function*

```
$($copy_button[0]).on("click", (event) => {
            show_tooltip($copy_button);
        });
```

## *Called function*

```
export function show_tooltip($copy_button) {
    // Display a tooltip to notify the user the version was copied.
    const instance = tippy($copy_button[0], {
        placement: 'top',
        onUntrigger() {
            remove_instance();
        },
    });
    instance.setContent("Copied!");
    instance.show();
    function remove_instance() {
        if (!instance.state.isDestroyed) {
            instance.destroy();
        }
    }
    setTimeout(remove_instance, 3000);
}
```

In Image 1 copied! confirmation placement it weird and I would like to make it the same as image 2. "Copied" is shown on click.

[image]

Here the copy code will be shown on hover and the placement is perfect.

[image]

This is the box structure for the image.

[image]

I just want the "Copied!" tooltip to be placed same as "copy code" tooltip. But for some reason the "Copied!" tooltip placement is weird. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What happens if you change the "Copied!" text to something longer (for example, Lorem ipsum sit dolor amet)? Does the placement stay the same as it is for `Copied!`? Also, what about the immediate parent of both the `Copy code` tooltip and the `Copied!` tooltip? Is it the same DOM element?

Comment: Hey it seems the immediate parent was the problem I just needed to add 
```   appendTo: () => document.body   ```
to the code part to get the result. Thank you very much for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
export function show_tooltip($copy_button) {
    // Display a tooltip to notify the user the version was copied.
    const instance = tippy($copy_button[0], {
        placement: 'top',
        appendTo: () => document.body,           //Just added this line.
        onUntrigger() {
            remove_instance();
        },
    });
    instance.setContent("Copied!");
    instance.show();
    function remove_instance() {
        if (!instance.state.isDestroyed) {
            instance.destroy();
        }
    }
    setTimeout(remove_instance, 3000);
}
```

Appending the element to document.body seems to help solve this problem.

Comment: this worked, but I found out it was to do with my document height. I added:

`style={{height:'calc(100vh)'}}` to my main wrapper and that fixed it for me